# Is pressure on a dam calculated by F/A or depth×density×$g$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, pressure

I had a question on a test where a dam was divided into two unequal parts and the question was about the pressure and force.

> [image]

I supposed that the area of the water in the X section is higher hence the pressure must be lower, but the actual answer is A. Why is that?

Comment: This is not a cross section, it's a top down view. Section X is not "higher".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The greater volume of water that is directly against the section will cancel out with the greater area - hence the two pressures will be the same.

Answer (score -1):

Pressure in a fluid at the same levels are equal, hence pressure at the two sections are equal.